# Null-conditional boolean in if statement

Tags: c#, winforms, events, boolean, null-conditional-operator

I have an `event` which returns a `boolean`. To make sure the event is only fired if anyone is listening, i call it using the null-conditional operator (questionmark). 
However, this means that I have to add the null-conditional operator to the returned boolean as well. And that means that I cannot figure out how to use it in an if-statement afterwards. Does anyone knows how to handle this?

```
switch (someInt) 
{
    case 1:
        // Validate if the form is filled correctly.
        // The event returns true if that is the case.
        bool? isValid = ValidateStuff?.Invoke();

        if (isValid)
            // If passed validation go to next step in form 
            GoToNextStep?.Invoke();
        break; 

    // There are more cases, but you get the point
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use

```
if (isValid.GetValueOrDefault())
```

which will give `false` if `isValid` is `null`.

or use the `??` operator

```
if (isValid ?? false)
```

which returns the value of the left operand if it is not `null` and the value of the right operand otherwise. So basically a shorthand for

```
if (isValid == null ? false : isValid)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in case of *Nullable* `bool?` you have [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic): `true`, `false` and `null` and thus you have to put *explicitly* if `null` should be treated as `true`, e.g.:

```
   if (isValid != false)     // either true or null
     GoToNextStep?.Invoke();
```

or `null` shall be considered as `false`:

```
   if (isValid == true)      // only true
     GoToNextStep?.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
if (isValid.HasValue && isValid.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to test wether `isValid` has a value:

```
if (isValid.HasValue && (bool)isValid)
```

Another option is to give `isValid` a default value when nobody is listening to your event. This can be done with the null coalescing operator:

```
bool isValid = ValidateStuff?.Invoke() ?? true;   // assume it is valid when nobody listens
```